# Can a div or anything.. do "margin:auto" but only permit padding for the text within it rather than fixed size or percentage?

Tags: css

If i want to create a div.. and place some text in it..

```
<div style="margin:auto;background-color:yellow;">test</div>
```

the problem is.. it is 100%..

i want it to simply have a padding over the text "text"

i do not want 100%.

but i want to use "margin:auto"

in other words..  "float:left" will not work with "margin:auto"

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more clearly? It is hard to understand your need in the question

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I think the OP want to align the div to the center by `margin:auto;` without specifying an explicit `width`.

Comment: @HashemQolami Then I think your answer is enough. Lemme upvote it :)

Comment: @HashemQolami - In that case, `div { display:table; }` is called for.

Comment: @Alohci While it's not designed for this purpose, it'd help to achieve the end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) such as `<div>` take the available space inside their containing block, if you do not want that, you should change `display` type of that element to something like `inline-block`.

Then you could give the `<div>` element some `padding` and align it centered horizintally by giving the parent a `text-align: center` declaration.

```css
.parent { text-align: center; }
.child { display: inline-block; padding: .5em 1em; background-color: gold; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```